# AngularJS: Inheritance for HTML Templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates

**Question:**

How do I prevent Code-Duplication in similar HTML-Templates?

**Description**

I have several different Templates for the same view/directive which I want to change depending on the environment. The templates are mostly identical but contain some parts which need to be changed depending on the environment.

**Example:**

A view to enter userdata might look like this to an admin:

```
<p> Username: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.username"></input>

<p> Firstname: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.firstname"></input>

<p> Lastname: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.lastname"></input>

<p> Authorization-level: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.authlevel"></input>
```

However I need to show basically the same view to a user without allowing him to change his Authorization-level:

```
<p> Username: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.username"></input>

<p> Firstname: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.firstname"></input>

<p> Lastname: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.lastname"></input>

<p> Authorization-level: </p>
{{ctrl.authlevel}}
```

I would like to prevent duplicating the code for both templates.

**Possible solutions:**

**ng-if**

Obviously, I could use `ng-if` to exchange html-blocks within a template depending on conditions. However, this does not scale well. The above example is simple, but imagine I have 5-10 different versions of a template. The code becomes increasingly hard to read with the number of versions of this template. Also, I would ideally like to prevent shipping the code for the admin-view to the user, which I can't if it is contained in the same html-file.

**custom directives**

I could wrap every HTML-node which needs to be replaced in its own directive. This would keep the main-template clean and I could exchange the HTML-Template for the directive depending on the environment. However, all those additional directives would cause a ton of boilerplate-code.

(This seems to be closest to Angular2's components though)

**third-party-library angular-blocks**

I found [angular-blocks](https://github.com/wmluke/angular-blocks) which seems to be tackling the issue I want to solve quite well . However, it doesn't seem to be very popular and looking at the implementation I am concerned that this might cause performance issues on large applications (due to several nested `$compile`-calls).

Are there any options that I am missing? Do you know about any best-practices or style-guides for this?

Comment: why not just use ng-disabled??

Comment: create a custom directive on the pattern of ng-formly, it would help you greatly...

Answer (score 3):

#### Make a template and use it with [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

I have a similar situation in my project where I use `ng-include` along with a couple ternaries or `ng-switch`es to achieve something similar to what you're looking for.

Put your first code block in a file and call it something like `userTemplate.js`. But change your authlevel section to account for the variation. In this case, I'd use `ng-switch` (but sometimes a ternary is all you need):

```
<p> Username: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.username"></input>

<p> Firstname: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.firstname"></input>

<p> Lastname: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.lastname"></input>

<p> Authorization-level: </p>
<div ng-switch="ctrl.authlevel">
  <p ng-switch-when="user">{{ ctrl.authlevel }}</p>
  <input ng-switch-when="admin" ng-model="ctrl.authlevel"></input>
</div>
```

Then everytime you need this chunk of code, you can use it in another view with `ng-include`. For example, in a user edit form:

```
<form class="user-form" ...>
  <div class="basic-info" ng-include="/path/to/userTemplate.js"></div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The nice thing with this approach is that with a little forethought and careful design, you can make these templates so versatile that they can be used for creating new resources or viewing or editing existing resources.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use `ng-switch`, and in the new angular 1.6 release candidate there is a option called `ng-switch-when-separator`. 
https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0-rc.2/docs/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch.
With it you can give multiple options to one `ng-switch-when`:

```
<div ng-switch="$ctrl.view">
  <p> Username: </p>
  <input ng-model="ctrl.username"></input>

  <p> Firstname: </p>
  <input ng-model="ctrl.firstname"></input>

  <p> Lastname: </p>
  <input ng-model="ctrl.lastname"></input>

  <p> Authorization-level: </p>
  <input ng-model="ctrl.authlevel" ng-switch-when="version1|version2|version3" ng-switch-when-separator="|"></input>
  <span ng-bind="ctrl.authlevel" ng-switch-when="version4|version5" ng-switch-when-separator="|"></span>
</div>
```

Another cool option could be Multi-slot transclusion (I have never used it) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: I think ng-switch comes mostly with the same issues as using ng-if, but is slightly more readable. The main issue I see here is that i have to ship all versions to every client. Multi-Slot transclusion seems to be a very viable option though. Sadly I can't use either of them since Multi-Slot transclusion was introduced in Angular 1.5 and i am stuck with an older Version for now. :/

Answer (score 0):

What's preventing you from wrapping the top section up in it's own template? This works when the dynamic content is above OR alongside the static content.

User-info-template.html

```
<p> Username: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.username"></input>

<p> Firstname: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.firstname"></input>

<p> Lastname: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.lastname"></input>
```

User-view.html

```
<user-info></user-info>
<p> Authorization-level: </p>
{{ctrl.authlevel}}
```

Admin-view.html

```
<user-info></user-info>
<p> Authorization-level: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.authlevel"></input>
```

---

This approach works when the dynamic content is a child of the static content:

User-info-template.html

```
<div>
    <p> Username: </p>
    <input ng-model="ctrl.username"></input>

    <p> Firstname: </p>
    <input ng-model="ctrl.firstname"></input>

    <p> Lastname: </p>
    <input ng-model="ctrl.lastname"></input>

    <!--Note that this dynamic piece is a child, so (as you noted)
    the above approach won't work-->
    <dynamic-piece></dynamic-piece>
</div>
```

Dynamic-piece-user.html

```
<p> Authorization-level: </p>
{{ctrl.authlevel}}
```

Dynamic-piece-admin.html

```
<p> Authorization-level: </p>
<input ng-model="ctrl.authlevel"></input>
```

I believe the component-based approach is flexible enough to accommodate for most situations.  However, it might be overkill for some things.  I (as a newbie angular developer) tend to start out using ng-ifs, and I break things down into components when they get too complicated.  I suggest you do the same.  Once you get the hang of refactoring components into different components, it's really a smooth workflow.

Comment: I have the impression that writing custom directives for the static parts causes the same (or similar) issues as writing custom directives for the dynamic parts of a template: As soon as i need to replace multiple HTML-Nodes and the Nodes are somewhere in the middle of the file, not at the beginning or the end I will need to manage several directives wich I need to split up even further if any new changes are added later on.

Comment: Also imagine that the custom input is added as content of another HTML-Node. This means the `<user-info>` directive needs to be followed by another custom directive to even produce correct HTML since it is missing the closing HTML-Tags or needs to contain quite a complex structure for multi-transclusion.

Comment: Hold on, I'll put together an example.  The best component approach depends on who the parent is in the DOM

Comment: This is what i described in the "custom directives" solution. I am not too worried about the workflow. I am rather concerned though that i need to write hundreds of non-reusable directives for this. Due to the amount of boilerplate code and additional files, this does not seem optimal to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom directive and pass data-type (user or admin) as a separate attribute. Here is an example using custom directive where the html structure of the form changes according to the value passed in the "data-type" attribute. So the input field will be shown only for data-type='user' or you can also check if authlevel value is available and show input field accordingly.

```
example:
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/YXkYgh73Kfn94O8wvA55?p=preview